# Typo3: User can't add meta data to files (permissions problem)

Tags: permissions, typo3, fal

When I log in as Administrator in my Typo3 installation, everything is fine. 
But I have created a user with limited rights. This user should be able (among other rights) to upload, edit, delete files and add meta data to these files.

This is how the user sees the file list:
[image]

This is how the administrator sees the file list:
[image]

So the user can add a new translation, but he can't modify the main language meta data record.

I have added a new group "editors" and assigned the following rights:

```
Access List -> Modules:
   File>Filelist ... yes
Access List -> Tables (listing):
   File Metadata ... yes
   File Reference ... yes
   File Storage ... yes
Access List -> Tables (modify):
   File ... yes
   File Collection ... yes
   File Metadata ... yes
   File Reference ... yes
   File Storage ... yes
Access List -> Allowed excludefields:
   File Metadata: yes to all
   File Collection: yes to all
Access List -> Limit to languages ... yes to all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the directory/file listing are some checkboxes.
Has your user checked the box for "Extended view"?

Without that check you (everyone) can access the allowed functions only by context menu.

Comment: Thank you, that was it - what a stupid feature. Cannot find any context menu in the file listing, btw.

Comment: context menu normaly is shown on (left) mouse click on the icon (preview-icon)